# ConstraintLayout unnecessary error

Tags: android, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

I'm using `ConstraintLayout` wrapped with `layout` tags for `dataBinding`, **all layouts works fine in execution and runtime**, but I got an annoying issue:

[image: xml screenshot]

As you see, constraint id's say "Cannot resolve symbol '@+id/tvAccount'", seemed as errors when trying to commit, but there's nothing wrong with workflow or the app, and all works fine as intended. It's same in all xml files. Cleaning, invalidating cache etc. is not fixing it. Has anyone met the same issue ?

Edit:
XML code for splash, it'll say "Cannot resolve symbol '@+id/imageViewSplash'" when you hover on the `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewSplash"` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <!--suppress AndroidUnknownAttribute -->
    <data class="SplashBinding"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.splash.SplashFragment">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewSplash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_splash_icon"
            android:src="@mipmap/splash_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewSplashLoader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_splash_loading"
            android:src="@mipmap/splash_loader"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewSplash"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Edit 2:
It's same error when you hover on `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewSplash"`, even without `<layout>` tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.splash.SplashFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSplash"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_splash_icon"
        android:src="@mipmap/splash_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSplashLoader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description_splash_loading"
        android:src="@mipmap/splash_loader"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewSplash"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: share your xml layout as text not as image thanks

Comment: @NileshRathod sharing as text does not highlight errors on here

Comment: @TimCastelijns it still persists after removing +

Comment: @MelihAksoy can u share your layout code

Comment: @MelihAksoy delete the constraint and again set it from Design tab.

Comment: @Nainal almost all constraints have same error through XML's no matter where it's set from, problem only exists for "app:layout_constraint" attributes that targets anything except "parent"

Answer (score 1):

After keeping layout in the editor i might have got the solution for you. The possible cause here is might be with the `xmlns:bind` and `xmlns:android`

Please try following it's not showing me any error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data></data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAccount"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:text="Account"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPhoneValidationTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone Validation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tvAccount"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tvAccount"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvAccount" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: No luck, it's same thing on layouts without binding ( I added another snippet ). Seems it's happening on "app:constraint" under all circumstances atm..

Comment: It's only showing error in the layout? Not troubling in the execution?

Comment: No, not at all. Everything is as expected and working for all the layouts in execution and runtime. It's an error in the XML editor only.

Comment: That's the strange behavior of studio.. Ha ha

Comment: Indeed.. And it doesn't look good when you want to commit, it keeps prompting there are 20 errors, all of them are these references lol

Comment: Try to invalidate and restart android studio. or rebuild the gradle. Maybe some dependencies are not loaded.

Comment: I just changed the version of ConstraintLayout and doing an invalidation. Will post if it makes any difference.

Comment: I come from the future. Invalidation worked for me. thanks @Brijesh Joshi

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the same issue by moving the `app` namespace from `<layout/>` to `<ConstraintLayout/>` tag.

Before:

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        ...>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

After:

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        ...>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```